# Bitcodes for extended ascii table (24x12pixel)

Tags: text, fonts, bitmap, ascii

I am using an LCD-Screen to display Output of my LPC1768 Microcontroller.

My display_on_LCD()-function uses a FONT24x16-header to display the right pixels on screen.
So each Ascii character can be represented by 24x16 pixels.

As an example bitmap for "A":
0x0000, 0x0380, 0x0380, 0x06C0, 0x06C0, 0x06C0, 0x0C60, 0x0C60,
0x1830, 0x1830, 0x1830, 0x3FF8, 0x3FF8, 0x701C, 0x600C, 0x600C,
0xC006, 0xC006, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000,

As i want to display the temperature on the LCD, what i need is the degree symbol: "°".

Does anyone have or know where to find byte codes for extended ascii characters (including "°") for resolution of 24x16 pixel?

Thanks